# Angular2 @Input no reflejar cambios al componente padre

Tags: angularjs-2.0, binding

Buenas, tengo un componente padre con un listado, al seleccionar se le pasa el elemento seleccionado al componente hijo (un formulario) definido con el decorador **@input**.

**El problema** Cuando modifico alguna propiedad en el formulario me replica el cambio en el listado

**Que espero** Que se replique el cambio una presionado submit

**El codigo**

*padre.html*

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Project List</h2>
    <button (click)="expandForm(true)" class="btn btn-default">New</button>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>State</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let project of projects" (click)="onSelect(project)">
                        <td>{{project.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{project.description}}</td>
                        <td>{{project.state.description}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
    <!--</div>-->
</div>
<project-form  [project]="selectedProject">
```

*Componente hijo*

```
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input()
    project: Project;

    constructor(private service: PService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

*hijo.html*

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #projectForm="ngForm" *ngIf="_project != null">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtName">Name</label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="project.name" type="text" class="form-control" id="txtName" name="Name"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtDescription">Description</label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="_project.description" type="text" class="form-control" id="txtDescription" name="Description"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ddlState">State</label>
        <select  [(ngModel)]="project.state" class="form-control" id="ddlState" name="State">
            <option *ngFor="let s of projectStates" [ngValue]="s">{{s.description}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" (click)="clear()" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Has tenido lugar de probar lo que te comento mas abajo? lo probe localmente y funciona. Saludos

Comment: la duda que me surge es que en el caso de una edicion tendria que setearle a projectAttachedToForm los datos de project. Esto lo tendria que manejar en el evento ngOnchange? Y no podria hacer this.projectAttachedToForm = this.project tendria hacer una especia de new Project("dato","dato","dato"); esto para no tener llegar al mismo problema de hoy que me quede bindiado al mismo objeto

Comment: Te añado eso a la respuesta :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create un objeto local en el formulario (projectAttachedToForm), que va a ser del mismo tipo y va a estar bindeado al formulario, pero sigues pasando el input al formulario.

Cuando pulses submit y todo este ok, haces lo siguiente:

```
this.project = this.projectAttachedToForm
```

Y debe de funcionarte perfectamente.

Como mejora, te recomendaría crear un evento output controlado en el padre, y dejar el component form solo para presentación y el padre, como smart, y así cuando guardes datos o edites y guardes en la BD, lo haces desde el Smart component siempre.

> http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-smart-components-vs-presentation-components-whats-the-difference-when-to-use-each-and-why/

**EDITO**

Para la edición del objeto en el formulario, tendrías que settear los objetos, pero no pasando la referencia como indico más arriba, para esto, tendrías que clonar el objeto sin pasar la referencia del mismo. Algo como esto:

```
var objeto1 = { name: "Mi nombre" };
var objeto2 = Object.assign({},objeto1);
```

También puedes probar con JSON.stringify y JSON.parse.

Comment: Gracias Alejandro, la duda que me surge es que en el caso de una edicion tendria que setearle a projectAttachedToForm los datos de project.
Esto lo tendria que manejar en el evento ngOnchange?
Y no podria hacer this.projectAttachedToForm = this.project tendria hacer una especia de new Project("dato","dato","dato"); esto para no tener llegar al mismo problema de hoy que me quede bindiado al mismo objeto